# Change Img based on Width of browser and Y position from top

Tags: javascript, jquery, css

I have some code that allows me to change the img src when I've scrolled from top < 120 px. But I need to change the image to another one when the browser is resized too.
 So I should get, 1 image when I scroll down 120 px, 1 image if I already scrolled down 120px but I reduced size of browser to 850 pixels,
  1 image if I'm at full top of browser, and another image if I reduce size of browser.

So far I can only change img src if I scroll 120px down, but how can I solve the browser size at the same time?

```
        $(window).on('scroll', function () {
            var scrollTop = $(window).scrollTop();
            if (scrollTop > 120) {
            $('#logo').attr('src', 'http://www.kubographics.com/adiacens/images/logo1-black.svg');
            $('#logo').css('margin-top', '10px');
            }
            else {
            ('#logo').attr('src', '');
            $('#logo').css('margin-top', '0px');
            }
            });
```

Thanks for your help!

Comment: You are looking for the same thing, but then `resize`, so `$(window).on('resize', function(){ if(window.innerWidth > x){ do Z; }}`

Comment: you have just `('#logo')` instead of `$('#logo')` at one point

Comment: @somethinghere thanks for your answer, but is possible to put them all on the same script? Because I did something in different scripts but only was working the scrolling thing instead of viewport.

This image helps to understand better what I'm trying to solve

![Valid XHTML] (http://www.kubographics.com/stackoverflow/EXAMPLE-01.png).

Answer (score 0):

To change the img use css media query

```
#logo {
background: url("http://www.kubographics.com/adiacens/images/logo1-black.svg")
}
@media (max-width: 850px) {
background: url("http://www.kubographics.com/adiacens/images/logo2-black.svg")
}
```